# Каким образом упросить код с помощью цикла?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите сократить код с помощью цикла

```
$('.e-info__1').addClass('slideInDown animated').find('.b-info__count').animateNumber({
  number: 1540
}, 4000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('.e-info__2').addClass('slideInDown animated').find('.b-info__count').animateNumber({
    number: 12040
  }, 3000);
}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('.e-info__3').addClass('slideInDown animated').find('.b-info__count').animateNumber({
    number: 1540
  }, 3000);
}, 1000);
```

**Решил след. образом**

```
var arrNumbers = [1540, 12040, 1540];
var i = 0;
$.each(arrNumbers, function(e) {
  e++;
  var num = parseInt(this.valueOf());
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.e-info__' + e).addClass('slideInDown animated').find('.b-info__count').animateNumber({
      number: num
    }, 3000);
  }, i);
  i += 500;
});
```

Comment: Ээх, а я хотел поумничать...а низя...

Comment: Тоды сюда поумничаю - https://gist.github.com/borodatych/894901adda59da7dd8d4

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен, что вам это поможет, так как закономерности в задаваемых параметрах я не вижу. Первое, что приходит в голову использовать:

```
// Получить все элементы имя класса которых начинается на "e-info__"
var elements = $('[class^="e-info__"]');

elements.each(function(indx, element){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(element).addClass('slideInDown animated').animateNumber({
            number: x
        }, y);
    }, z);
});
```

С генерирование параметров извольте разобраться сами...
Либо воспользуйтесь вариантом @borodatych.
Решения одинаковы, разница в том я получаю массив существующих элементов со страницы, а в его решении вам заранее нужно знать индентификаторы.

Comment: Может чего не понимаю, но у вас упущен setTimeout. Вы его случайно потеряли, или есть какой то смысл в этом?

Comment: Не специально, смотрел в первую строку сообщения, а там он не использовался...
Следует ли мне исправлять? Ответ уже дан...

Comment: Думаю, все же стоит. Вдруг кому больше подойдет именно Ваше решение.

Comment: @borodatych На самом деле, наши решения идентичны, мое было раньше, но не столь точным.

Comment: Свое я еще вчера написал, но так как вопрос был на принятии редактирования, ответы давать было нельзя. И как бэ закинился в комменте у ответа ;)

Comment: @borodatych Линку не дадите, что за принятие редактирования, и почему в это время на вопрос нельзя отвечать...

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам действительно нужно такое разное поведение то как то так:

```
var arr = {
    1:{
        anime:4000,
        number:1540,
        pause:0
    },
    2:{
        anime:3000,
        number:12040,
        pause:500
    },
    3:{
        anime:3000,
        number:1540,
        pause:1000
    }
};
$.each(arr,function(i,e){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.e-info__'+i).addClass('slideInDown animated').find('.b-info__count').animateNumber({
            number: arr[i].number
        },arr[i].anime);
    },arr[i].pause);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы как-нибудь так сделал

Вариант 1 (гибкий)

```
var mAddClass = function(b){
    if(typeof b!='object'){var b={};}//чтобы избежать ошибки при использовании ф-ции без параметров
    var a = {i:1, number: 1540, an_time: 3000, timeout: 0};//значения по умолчанию 
    for(var k in b){a[k]=b[k];}//все из b сгоняется в a с заменой элементов по-умолчанию на новые
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.e-info__'+a.i).addClass('slideInDown animated').find('.b-info__count').animateNumber({
       number: a.number
    },a.an_time);
},a.timeout);
}

mAddClass({an_time: 4000});
mAddClass({i:2,number: 12040, timeout: 500});
mAddClass({i:3, timeout: 1000});
```

Вариант 2 (жесткий)

```
mAddClass = function(a){ 
    setTimeout(function () {
    //Тоже, что и в 1ом примере, только без значений по умолчанию (за ненадобностью)
    $('.e-info__'+a.i).addClass('slideInDown animated').find('.b-info__count').animateNumber({
       number: a.number
    },a.an_time);
},a.timeout);
}


for(var ind = 1; ind<=3; ind++){
    var a = {i:ind, number: ((ind==2)? 12040 : 1540), an_time: ((ind===1)? 4000 : 3000), timeout: ((ind-1)*500)}; 
    //number во 2м 12040, в остальных - 1540; также и с параметром для animateNumber an_time; setTimeout каждый раз увеличивается на 500 - т.е. (ind-1)*500 - (1-1=0)*500=0, (2-1=1)*500=500, (3-1=2)*500=1000
    mAddClass(a);
}
```

P.S.: Если кому-то просто пригодится - ф-ция для присвоения значений по умолчанию вынесена отдельно

```
var margeObjects = function(a,b){//ф-ция слияния 2х объектов (не помню, может такая уже существует?
    if(typeof a!='object'){var a={};} if(typeof b!='object'){var b={};}//чтобы избежать ошибки при использовании ф-ции без параметров 
    for(var k in b){a[k]=b[k];}//присвоение всего содержимого объекта b к a
    return a;//возвращаем полученный объект
}

var mAddClass = function(b){ 
    var b = margeObjects({i:1, number: 1540, an_time: 3000, timeout: 0},b);
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.e-info__'+a.i).addClass('slideInDown animated').find('.b-info__count').animateNumber({
       number: a.number
    },a.an_time);
},a.timeout);
}

mAddClass({an_time: 4000});
```